# iOS UIImageView inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have Xcode 4.5 Mater-Detail Application with this structure:
[image]

If you click some cell in Master View, you see the image in Detail View. All works fine. 
But I want to scroll my images, couse sometimes they are larger than the screen.

I embed my ImageView in ScrollView. Than I connected my UIScollView with property inside code:

MainStoryBoard.storyboard - DetailViewController.h
[image]

To check scroller's content size problem, I make it very big:

DetailViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width+1000,
    self.scrollView.frame.size.height+1000)];

    [self configureView];
}
//edit:
- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.
    if (self.detailItem) {
        self.title = self.detailItem.data.title;
        self.imageView.image = self.detailItem.fullImage;
    }
}
```

But it does not work. Why?

Comment: What are you doing in configureView method? Hope you are not changing content size in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did u try increasing the size of your

```
UIView
```

You can set it as freeform under the Simulated Metrics -> Size and then change the size respectively or programmatically change it, as your scrollview is nested within your view